# C error assignment to expression with array type

Tags: c, arrays

I have to write a code, which first reads a matrix from a file and then displays it. And it also has to sum the columns of matrix and find the biggest sum and display it. Compiler says on line 23 there's and error: assignment to expression with array type. How to fix it(beside all the other mistakes I have)?

Thank you in advance.
Here is my [code](http://pastebin.com/fZPJAZhY).

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS 15
#define COLS 15

int readMatrix(int r,int c, int Matrix[ROWS][COLS]);
void printMatrix(int Matrix[ROWS][COLS], int r,int c);  
int Sum(int Matrix[ROWS][COLS], int r,int c);
void Congratulations(int Matrix[COLS], int c);

int main(void)
{ 
    int Sales[ROWS][COLS];
    int Kokku[COLS];
    int rows, cols;
    int Matrix[ROWS][COLS];

    scanf("%d", &rows); //loeb dokumendist ridade arvu
    scanf("%d", &cols); //loeb dokumendist veergude arvu

    readMatrix(rows, cols, Matrix); //maatriksi sisselugemine
    printMatrix(Matrix, rows, cols); //maatriksi väljaprint
    Kokku = Sum(Sales, rows, cols); //müügitulemuste arvutus
    Congratulations(Kokku, cols); //Parima leidmine ja tunnustus

    return 0; 
}
int readMatrix(int r,int c, int Matrix[ROWS][COLS])
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int sellingTable;
    for(i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &Matrix[i][j]);
            sellingTable = i;
        }
    scanf("\n");
    }
    return sellingTable;
}
void printMatrix(int Matrix[ROWS][COLS], int r,int c)
{
    int i, j;
    printf("Tabel:");
    j = 0;
    do
    {
        printf("M%2d", j + 1);
        j++;
    }
    while(j <= c);
    for(i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
    printf("Kaup%2d", i + 1);
        for(j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            printf("%4d", Matrix[i][j]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }
}
int Sum(int Matrix[ROWS][COLS], int r,int c)
{
    int i, j, sum;
    int Summa[c];

    printf("Kokku:");

    for(j = 0, sum = 0; j < c; j++)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < r; i++)
        {
            sum = Matrix[i][j] + sum;
            Summa[j] = sum;
        }
    printf("%4d", Summa[j]);
    }
    return sum;
}
void Congratulations(int Matrix[COLS], int c)
{
    int j, temp;
    for(j = 0; j < c; j++)
    {
        if(Matrix[j]>Matrix[j + 1])
        {
            temp = Matrix[j];
            Matrix[j] = Matrix[j + 1];
            Matrix[j + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
    printf("Parim; nr %d, %d", c, Matrix[c]);
}
```

Comment: 1. Don't post links to code, they can be become invalid. 2. Isolate your error and only post the relevant sections. 3. `Sum` returns an `int` and you are trying to assign it to as an array (`int Kokku[COLS]`). Your compiler is quite clear on what the problem is, where are you having trouble with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int Kokku[COLS];
...
Kokku = Sum(Sales, rows, cols);
```

Simply do as the compiler says and don't try to assign the result of a function returning `int` to a variable which is an array of `int`.